# How can I zip the contents of a nested zip using gradle

Tags: gradle

I have the following source zip file (`outer.zip`) that contains an `inner.zip` file which, itself, contains two .txt files:

```
outer.zip          
   +--inner.zip   
         +--a.txt
         +--b.txt
```

I need to create a `new.zip` file, that contains the contents of the `inner.zip` file (the two .txt files) i.e.

```
new.zip           
   +--a.txt     
   +--b.txt
```

The following gradle seems to work fine:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

task unzipInnerZip(type: Copy) {
    from (zipTree('outer.zip'))
    include 'inner.zip'
    into "${buildDir}/temp/extracted"
}

task buildNewZip(type: Zip, dependsOn: unzipInnerZip) {
    baseName = 'new'
    from (zipTree("${buildDir}/temp/extracted/inner.zip"))
}

assemble.dependsOn(buildNewZip)
```

My question is, how can I achieve the same result, without extracting the inner.zip file to a named temp directory - my current solution doesn't quite feel like the "gradle way".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed the following structure:

```
- 2.zip
 - 1.zip
  - a.txt
  - b.txt
```

If above, it can be done with the following piece of code:

```
task buildZip(type: Zip) {
    baseName = 'new'
    from (zipTree(zipTree(file('2.zip')).files.find { it.name == '1.zip' }))
}
```

With the following line:

```
zipTree(file('2.zip')).files.find { it.name == '1.zip' }
```

`1.zip` is found among the entries of `2.zip`. Then it's used as a `zipTree` feed.

Your solution works perfectly fine and also represents *gradle way* - remember about SRP ;)